# Svelte value not reactive

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I've a variable `styles` in the Svelte store that I would like to update:

```
export const styles = writable();
```

Now in my `mainframe.svelte` file, I've an EventListener that listens to a click and updates the store value as follow:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    styles.update(() => getComputedStyle(e.target));
});
```

And in my `spacing.svelte` file, I want to console.log when the value changes, but it's not at all updating and stuck at **undefined**:

```
$: console.log(get(styles));
```

Now if I use `setInterval` then it is working and updating the values as per clicks, so it's definitely not the code but the problem is with reactivity itself:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(get(styles));
}, 1000);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why the value is not changing automatically on clicks but `setInterval` seems to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because of how reactivity works.
In your code `$: console.log(get(styles));` you have the following parts:

`$:` this marks the line as reactive, it will run again when any variable (or function) used on that line changes.
`console.log`, this never changes
`get`, this is a helper function from the stores, it never changes
`styles`, this is the *store* it never changes (the value does, but not the store itself)

conclusion: this line is run once and then never again.

the solution is simple, instead of doing `get` which is used to get the current value of a store **once** (and usually only used in script files where reactivity doesn't work), you can simply use the value itself:

```js
$: console.log($styles);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your brilliant answer! You really have a profound knowledge about the web. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Even in script files `get` might be a sign that something is off and possibly a `derived` store should be used instead.